# Using SSH/SFTP as an alternative to Samba?

Tags: linux, ssh, samba, openssh, sftp

I'm told using SSH/SFTP is a more secure alternative to Samba to edit a web server from a Windows host.

However, I can't find how use it to create a path like Z:\ between Windows and OpenSSH: The only examples I find are either a terminal window or a Norton Commander-style GUI to copy files back and forth.

What solution can I use to create an SSH tunnel to a remote OpenSSH server so that the user simply has to double-click a folder in Network Neighbordood like Samba does?

Thank you.

Comment: A samba server should not be open to the internet... firewall it now.

Comment: You will not be able to use "_Network Neighbourhood_" to view a remote directory over SSH/SFTP, but you could mount a "_Network Share_".

Comment: It is firewalled: Only TCP80 is reachable from the Net. I'll look into "Network Share" over SSH, and SSHFS (provided it's not the same thing). Thank you.

Comment: ("_Network Share_" as in `net use * \\%SERVER%\%SHARE%` or "_Map Network Drive_")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you are running a Linux or Unix based server and a Windows client.

Assuming the server is set up correctly, one way of doing this is to use a SFTP client such as `Filezilla` or `WinSCP`.

Once you have this set up correctly, you will be able to securely connect to the remote server to copy over the required files. This would involve using the Filezilla client which may not be your preferred option.

Another option is to use `SSHFS`. This allows you to mount your SSH server as if it was a directory. This may be best eventually, but I would probably test with Filezilla first so you know that everything works ok. I am not sure how stable the win-sshfs project is, but it sounds like it offers the functionality you are looking for:

https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs/releases (latest release February 2016)

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it's OpenSSH running on Linux, and a Windows client.

I don't want to use Filezilla or WinSCP to copy files: The user must be able to edit the files directly over SSH by double-clicking a folder in Net Neighborhood, like with Samba. I guess this invoves an SSH tunnel.

Comment: Please don't link to the archived Google Code page (latest release in 2012)... use the new [GitHub](https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs/releases) page (latest release in 2015). Additionally, please include a note in your answer about the age of the latest release.